# Dash Interactive table

Tags: python, dataframe, dash

Ищу способ создания интерактивной таблицы для редактирования и добавления данных,
как можно реализовать, добавления колонки  "Actions" в ячейке которых можно поместить кнопки действия с текущей строкой,
Просьба, подсказать возможно ли подобное реализовать в dash?
Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951099/save-a-modified-dash-datatable-to-dataframe

Comment: спасибо, не совсем то что ищу, мне нужно получить саму таблицу подобного формата
"
column1 | column2 | column3 | Actions
123        |    435      |  534        | buttons actions 
"
где соответственно кнопки отвечают за текущую строку (удаление редактирование)

Comment: Судя по тексту вашего вопроса, по моей ссылке находится как раз именно то, что вы ищите.

Comment: функционал да, но элементы управления и редактирования вынесены отдельно,
для наглядности нашел в сети вид что хочу получить, прикладываю ссылку 
https://d1klenmqvfdv9g.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Figure-1.2-2.png
т.е. нужно в таблице создать колонку Actions в ячейках которых помещать кнопки взаимодействия с текущей строкой,